# Analog (?) short Story early 1970s widespread computer use in near contemporary society

Tags: story-identification, computers

This question:

[Even in the 1960s, was the UI/.computer systems of The Enterprise being criticized?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269621/even-in-the-1960s-was-the-ui-computer-systems-of-the-enterprise-being-criticiz)

Remined me of a story I'd like to identify.

I remember a science fiction story probably in *Analog* probably during the early 1970s when there was some sort of breakdown of all the computers in a small town.  The characters didn't realize how many computers there were in town and all the things that they were used for until the computers started malfunctioning.  This should have been before the first "microcomputers" (personal computers) so the computers would have been mainframes or minicomputers.

I remember wondering at the time whether the computer dependent society in the story was supposed to be a near future setting or the actual present.